# Why do I get this error while building an APK with Cordova?

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, gradle, apk

I'm trying to make an APK of a web app, I wrapped it into Cordova.
I followed various tutorials, installed Gradle and made it work.

When i run `cordova build android ---verbose`  from CMD, I get this error:

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Running command: C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Tlf Cordova\AngularToMobileProject-master\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Tlf Cordova\AngularToMobileProject-master\platforms\android\build.gradle
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load wrapper properties from 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Tlf Cordova\AngularToMobileProject-master\platforms\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.<init>(WrapperExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.forWrapperPropertiesFile(WrapperExecutor.java:45)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:62)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 16: C:UsersUSERDownloadsgradle-6.3-bin.zip
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3058)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.readDistroUrl(WrapperExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.prepareDistributionUri(WrapperExecutor.java:67)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.<init>(WrapperExecutor.java:54)
        ... 2 more
Command finished with error code 1: C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Tlf Cordova\AngularToMobileProject-master\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug,-b,C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Tlf Cordova\AngularToMobileProject-master\platforms\android\build.gradle
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Tlf Cordova\AngularToMobileProject-master\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load wrapper properties from 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Tlf Cordova\AngularToMobileProject-master\platforms\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.<init>(WrapperExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.forWrapperPropertiesFile(WrapperExecutor.java:45)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:62)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 16: C:UsersUSERDownloadsgradle-6.3-bin.zip
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3058)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.readDistroUrl(WrapperExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.prepareDistributionUri(WrapperExecutor.java:67)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.<init>(WrapperExecutor.java:54)
        ... 2 more
Error: C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Tlf Cordova\AngularToMobileProject-master\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load wrapper properties from 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Tlf Cordova\AngularToMobileProject-master\platforms\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.<init>(WrapperExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.forWrapperPropertiesFile(WrapperExecutor.java:45)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:62)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 16: C:UsersUSERDownloadsgradle-6.3-bin.zip
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3058)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.readDistroUrl(WrapperExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.prepareDistributionUri(WrapperExecutor.java:67)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.<init>(WrapperExecutor.java:54)
        ... 2 more
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Tlf Cordova\AngularToMobileProject-master\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Tlf Cordova\AngularToMobileProject-master\node_modules\cordova-common\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
```

Using **Gradle 6.3**

I tried a lot of tutorials and StackOverflow solution, but none of them work for me.

My **gradle-wrapper.properties**

> ## Tue Oct 16 17:39:45 IST 2018
>
> distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
>
> distributionPath=wrapper/dists
>
> zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
>
> zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
>
> distributionUrl=C:\Users\USER\Downloads\gradle-6.3-bin.zip

Answer (score 0):

I am using gradle 5.1.1 for cordova9.0.
There is no problems.

Comment: Obviously it doesn't solve my issue, do you think it's a versions issue? we're using the same Cordova version

Comment: I tried with dowgrading Gradle, but the problem remains just as before...

Comment: You have to retry to remove and add platform.

cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android